# SSL VPN packet structure

Tags: tls, vpn

What is the exact structure of a packet flowing inside a SSL based VPN? What parts of the packet are authenticated and what parts are encrypted?
From my understanding there are two types of SSL VPN: Portal VPN and Tunnel VPN. What are the difference between the two at a packet level?

In IPsec VPN there are AH or ESP header there is something similar also in SSL VPN?

Comment: You can find that on the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246

Comment: Isn't tls 1.2 obsolete? The rfc never mentions vpn, the structure it's exactly the same?

Comment: If you refer to OpenVPN's implementation of SSL/TLS tunnels, the protocol is documented here: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/openvpn-protocol/

Comment: Contrary to IPSec or Wireguard there is no standard or open specification for SSL VPN. There are various products with this phrase which are usually proprietary and don't interact with each other. They have in common that they use TLS as for protection, but the structure inside TLS depends on the specific implementations.